# Neptune 3 Pro + OrcaSlicer + Thumbnail

Tags: printing, 3d

I need your help. I bought 3D printer Neptune 3 Pro and I don't know how can I setup Thumbnail. Thumbnail looks like that:

[image]

I use OrcaSlicer. I already try this plugin https://github.com/Molodos/ElegooNeptuneThumbnails, but it is nothing happened. I got SD card with original benchy and there was an image. If I create with OrcaSlicer then I have a problem... there is no image.